# Razor page does not read from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am building a simple CRUD table. I have successfully built the table and am able to make a connection string. However, the razor page only displays the page headers and is unable to retrieve the table data. See the .cshtml.cs and the .chtml razor page below respectively.

This is the cshtml.cs code:

```cs
public void OnGet() {
  try {
    string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-96RUE45\\TEW_SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mystore;Integrated Security=True";
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
      connection.Open();
      string sql = "SELECT * FROM PipeSizes";
      using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
        using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            PipeInfo pipeInfo = new PipeInfo();
            pipeInfo.ID = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
            pipeInfo.ImpNPS = "" + reader.GetDecimal(1);
            pipeInfo.ImpWT = "" + reader.GetDecimal(2);
            pipeInfo.ImpWeight = "" + reader.GetDecimal(3);
            pipeInfo.Identification = reader.GetString(4);
            pipeInfo.SchNo = "" + reader.GetInt32(5);
            pipeInfo.MetricNPS_DN = "" + reader.GetDecimal(6);
            pipeInfo.MetricOD = "" + reader.GetDecimal(7);
            pipeInfo.MetricWeight = "" + reader.GetDecimal(8);

            listPipes.Add(pipeInfo);

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
  }
}

public class PipeInfo {
  public string ID;
  public string ImpNPS;
  public string ImpOD;
  public string ImpWT;
  public string ImpWeight;
  public string Identification;
  public string SchNo;
  public string MetricNPS_DN;
  public string MetricOD;
  public string MetricWT;
  public string MetricWeight;
}
```

And here is the razor page:

```html
@page
@model MyStore.Pages.Pipes.PipesModel
@{
}

<br>
<h2> List of Pipe Sizes</h2>
<a class='btn-primary btn-sm'href='/Pipes/Create'>New Pipe Size</a>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>ImpNPS</th>
            <th>ImpOD</th>
            <th>ImpWT</th>
            <th>ImpWeight</th>
            <th>Identification</th>
            <th>SchNo</th>
            <th>MetricNPS_DN</th>
            <th>MetricOD</th>
            <th>MetricWT</th>
            <th>MetricWeight</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model.listPipes)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ID</td>
                <td>@item.ImpNPS</td>
                <td>@item.ImpOD</td>
                <td>@item.ImpWT</td>
                <td>@item.ImpWeight</td>
                <td>@item.Identification</td>
                <td>@item.SchNo</td>
                <td>@item.MetricNPS_DN</td>
                <td>@item.MetricOD</td>
                <td>@item.MetricWT</td>
                <td>@item.MetricWeight</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Pipes/Edit?id=@item.ID">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="/Pipes/Delete?id=@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When you debug it items are being added to your listPipes?

Comment: I suspect not and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: If the items are not being added in listPipes then the problem is most likely with how you are fetching data. Better check the authorization, db connection and whether the records exist etc. Basics though but never the least ones to make sure.

Comment: Replace unnecessary comments from title with more problem specification (ie. "when reading from database")

Comment: @TouchAndGo please verify, that your model is not null and contains items, after your sql code has run and then please add your page definition.

Comment: Hi @Marco Can you give me a link to a resource that shows how I can do that? Many thanks.

Comment: Simply set a breakpoint and validate by hand.